# Why does Genie rewear the cuffs?

Tags: plot-explanation, aladdin

At the end of Disney's *Aladdin*, Aladdin frees Genie with his last wish, and the cuffs, that are presumably keeping Genie imprisoned, vanish.

[image: GenieCuffsVanishing]

[image: GenieFree]

These cuffs are still not present when Genie leaves to see the world.

[image: GeniePacking]

### However

When Genie returns in *Return of Jafar*, the cuffs are back.

[image: GenieRoJCuffsBack]

They are also present in the second sequel *The King of Thieves* and in the TV series too.

[image: GenieTKoT] [image: GenieTVSeries]

As far as I am aware, Genie is a free Genie in all these subsequent appearances.

**Is there any reason for Genie still wearing cuffs after he has been freed by Aladdin?**

Comment: Because without cuffs his hands looks lame ;)

Comment: Maybe they are not the same cuffs. Genie probably chose the new ones himself.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Aesthetically, I like Genie with cuffs more than Genie without them.

It also serves a visual purpose when we see Genie's dismembered hands doing things by themselves (which happens on several occasions), and the cuffs provide a nice visual cutoff for his hands (literally).

This seems to be a real world consideration, as opposed to having a justification in the fictional universe. Genie's character design would have regressed if the cuffs had been removed.

Presumably, sequels hadn't been considered before the Aladdin story (including Genie losing the cuffs) was finalized, and it simply wasn't considered for future compatibility.